# how to run a shell script in jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, sh

I use jenkins to package and start my java project，so I add a post step in build

[image: build in jenkins]

and the start.sh is simple

```sh
./provider/bin/start.sh
./provider-groundnet/bin/start.sh
./consume/bin/start.sh
./provider-skynet/bin/start.sh
```

the problem is after build my project did not start up

```
+ /bin/sh -ex start.sh
+ ./provider/bin/start.sh
start com.nb.xry.provider.FinanceProviderApplication success!
+ ./provider-groundnet/bin/start.sh
start com.nb.xry.groundnet.provider.FinanceProviderGroundnetApplication success!
+ ./consume/bin/start.sh
start com.nb.xry.consume.FinanceConsumeApplication success!
+ ./provider-skynet/bin/start.sh
start com.nb.xry.skynet.FinanceProviderSkynetApplication success!
+ exit
Finished: SUCCESS
```

if I add a "sleep" command before "exit" like this

```
/bin/sh -ex start.sh
sleep 10000
exit
```

so I guess the `start.sh` script has been execute successfully, but when jenkins finish the build it will kill all the process it created, am I right? and how to make the process still running after build finished

Comment: Have you tried running them in background ? Add & in end of line. example ./provider/bin/start.sh &
./provider-groundnet/bin/start.sh &
./consume/bin/start.sh &
./provider-skynet/bin/start.sh &

Comment: @ShreedharDhanawade   if I not use jenkins, just use ssh to login my linux server and run the start.sh with `/bin/sh start.sh`, the process works fine, even I close the terminal the process will continue to run，so I thinks the process already run in background